# SharePoint Sending Background Emails

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript

I have written code (HTML, CSS, JavaScript) that will reside in a SharePoint content webpart. The goal is a user selects a few options from a checkbox than an email with be sent to our org box to respond to their request. The issue that I am experiencing is the user receives an internet security pop-up and then they have to manually send the email. We want it in the background. I did create a seperate button, so that a SharePoint list form can appear and an email can be sent via a workflow. The issue with that is I can't pass the value selected in the javascipt checkbox to the workflow, so we know what the user selected. Need to use a javascript checkbox form for several reasons. Does anyone know a way to send an email in background, I read about a SharePoint email utility, but can't get it to work. Assuming it is a server setting. Basicially want the email sent without involving user.

Comment: You can get the checkbox value like `[%Current Item: FieldName%]`. Try throwing a conditional in there `If [%Current Item: FieldName%] equals VALUE` then send your email

Comment: In addition to my answer - to help others understand your question, try to add some formatting to your question to make it more readable / understandable. Add your code since it's mostly helpful to understand the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If enabled you can use SharePoint to send the mail - example code:

```
var sendMailUtil = (function (_this) {
    //create a scope so the variables dont collide with other

    var sendMail = function (fromMail, toMailArray, Subject, Body) {
        var formDigest = document.getElementById("__REQUESTDIGEST").value;
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + '/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail');

        xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json;odata=verbose');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'application/json;odata=verbose');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-RequestDigest', formDigest);

        //no need since it's fire and forget
        //xhr.onload = function () { console.log('onload event') };

        var data = {
            'properties': {
                '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Utilities.EmailProperties' },
                'From': fromMail,
                'To': { 'results': toMailArray },
                'Subject': Subject,
                'Body': Body
            }
        };
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    };
    //export the function to the public object
    _this.sendMail = sendMail;
    return _this;
})({});
//you can also attach this function to the global scope like this
// window.sendMailUtil = sendMailUtil;

//this will send a mail 
sendMailUtil.sendMail('from@mail.de', ['to1@mail.de', 'to2@mail.de'], 'Mail Subject', 'Mail body');
```

Comment: thank you for your quick response, how can I check if enabled? Is that a SharePoint server setting. The server is controlled by another team in another state.

Comment: It's actually not that easy to disable. Our infrastructure guy somehow got it done since it's more or less a security flaw (I mean you can send to everyone from everyone). Most likely it's enabled on your environment.

Comment: ok I will add it, question for you. I was an old school programmer (COBOL/JCL, Assembler) back in the day, then moved to networking for many years. The last two years I had to learn programming again - HTML and CSS, then the last 6 months, had to learn JavaScript. So I am still a little bit of a rookie. So to test this code, I was going to implement it as a standalone. Will that work or do I need to somehow call it with the program. I am assuming that I need to change the from, to, subject and body - correct? Sorry for my elementary questions?

Comment: I updated the code so it will work like a small utility.  Collect the data from where it's aviable and call the utility as explained.

Comment: for some reason it is not working, probably just something that I am not understand, so do I call sendMailUtility or sendmail and pass it the values, I am doing the latter. I will attach my code

Comment: <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cs3.eis.af.mil/sites/OO-OT-AM-87/Style Library/Scripts/jquery.maphilight.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  
  <script type="text/javascript">
  sendMailSP(john.colonnello.ctr@us.af.mil, john.colonnello.ctr@us.af.mil, Please Work, Test);

Comment: oh well -> you need to put the strings in `'` or `"` so javascript does not think it's an object. Also the second parameter needs to be an array. Stick to my example and simply replace the emails without removing the `'`.

Comment: Tip: Use the Chrome Browser and learn to use Chrome Snippets, with a SharePoint page opened (thus authenticated) you can then easily work with these small code fragments.  https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/snippets

Comment: Also check the browser console. It will tell you which error occured. In addition use a IDE with JavaScript support. Syntax checking and highlighting will help you sort out the easier errors.

Comment: @Mx. that IIFE is too complex for the average JS Joe here, just a sendMail function is enough, IMHO

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman perfectly right. Maybe you could edit/delete his comment where he reveals internal mails. 

@ Johnny C. you should never publish your companies mails if not intended.

Comment: I can't delete other comments. But they are US military .. wouldn't worry about those.. the Russians have them already .. or Johnny is a Russian hacker.. ;-)